# how to disable / enable jquery mobile buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, disabled-input

I am trying to disable the button I tap on and enable the rest. Here is an example

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" class="status" value="Input1">
    <input type="button" class="status" value="Input2" disabled="">
    <input type="button" class="status" value="Input3" disabled="">
</div>

var container = $('.container');

container.on("click", '.status', function () {
    $('.status').prop('disabled', false).button(); // set all buttons to enabled
    $(this).prop('disabled', true).button();  // set the one I clicked to disabled
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DU7PF/1/)

But it's not working, How can I accomplish enable\disable with jQuery-mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to disable after initialization:

```
$('.status').button('enable');
$(this).button('disable');
```

Always check the [API site](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable)

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DU7PF/3/)

Comment: still, can't make it work on my example.The buttons don't get enhanced. And i'm not sure jquery ui works the same like jquery mobile

Comment: use $('.status').removeAttr('disabled') instead to enable them. Most browsers only check if disabled attribute is present, and don't really matter what it's value is.

Comment: @Patrioticcow, sorry the code and links were good for jquery UI, not mobile. I fixed the code and links for your needs.

Comment: @user1600124, this is not the case when jQuery ui\mobile is controlling the elements, try it in jsFiddle.